# iOS Home Screen visible through an app

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if you can make the home screen visible through an app.

For example, let's take an example from the Apple Calculator. On macOS, the top is blurred and you can see everything through it.

I know iOS is a whole different OS and works through views and not tabs, but still: is it possible to e.g. blur the top of the iOS calculator and see the home screen through it?

Thanks, Ben

Comment: It is not possible to access the Home Screen from an iOS app on a non-jailbroken iDevice. This is due to the sandbox restriction of the individual apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, as this could be a serious breach of privacy for iPhone users.

If you could make the home screen visible through an app, a developer could technically save pictures of users' homescreens and store them in a remote database, which could give them access to private information. As a result, Apple doesn't allow you to do this.